# How do I run a sql scripts in POWERSHELL that starts with a specific name and I do not know the last half of the name?

Tags: sql, powershell

This is my script...

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "database" -Username "QQQ" -Password "abc123$" -Database "Cars" -InputFile $PathToGamePreset"PreIn*.sql" -Verbose
```

Error...

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Illegal characters in path. At line:59 char:5

Comment: `gci -Path $PathToGamePreset"PreIn*.sql"` and thentry each one separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Abra mentions, the first step is to get the file name first with `Get-ChildItem`, and then you can run the SQL script.

If you have only a single file matching the path, you can do something like this:

```
$SQLFile = Get-ChildItem $PathToGamePreset"PreIn*.sql"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "database" -Username "QQQ" -Password "abc123$" -Database "Cars" -InputFile $SQLFile.FullName -Verbose
```